# Could not show text shadow of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make text shadow effect for my text. So I use shadow attributes of TextView. But I don't know why it could not show the shadow, I have checked on both Android Studio Layout Preview and on real device Galaxy S3 but nothing happen.

Help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text Shadow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try `android:shadowDx="12"
        android:shadowDy="12"
        android:shadowRadius="8"`

Comment: nothing happen...still not find the reason

Comment: The text color is **black**, the text shadow color is **half black**... `can you tell the difference`? try setting the shadow color to **red**, just for experiment... so you can see it clearly (well, `depending on your background dominant color`, of course).

Comment: Yes, it is the reason. Since I have checked on device, with small font it's almost same and I think it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shadowColor="#000"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="50"
    android:text="Text Shadow Example1"
    android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Text Shadow Example2"
    android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to make one xml fiile named **shadow_bg.xml** and place define drawable to your textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#b0000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000" />

</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Text Shadow Example2"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_bg"
    android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

It works fine for me. Hope it works fine for you as well.